# How do I create a function or procedure for this kind of separate functions

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Sub CheckTwo(ByVal str As String)
    If ((arrayTwo(colArray(0), colArray(0)) = str) And (arrayTwo(colArray(1), colArray(1)) = str)) Or
        ((arrayTwo(colArray(0), colArray(1)) = str) And (arrayTwo(colArray(1), colArray(0)) = str)) Then

        MsgBox(str + " Won")

    End If

    For i = 0 To colArray.Length - 1

        If (arrayTwo(colArray(i), colArray(0)) = str) And (arrayTwo(colArray(i), colArray(1)) = str) Or
            (arrayTwo(colArray(0), colArray(i)) = str) And (arrayTwo(colArray(1), colArray(i)) = str) Then
            MsgBox(str + " Won")

        End If
    Next

End Sub

Public Sub CheckThree(ByVal str As String)
    If ((arrayTwo(colArray(0), colArray(0)) = str) And (arrayTwo(colArray(1), colArray(1)) = str) And
        (arrayTwo(colArray(2), colArray(2)) = str)) Or
       ((arrayTwo(colArray(0), colArray(2)) = str) And (arrayTwo(colArray(1), colArray(1)) = str) And
        (arrayTwo(colArray(2), colArray(0)) = str)) Then

        MsgBox(str + " Won")

    End If

        For i = 0 To colArray.Length - 1

        If ((arrayTwo(colArray(0), colArray(i)) = str) And (arrayTwo(colArray(1), colArray(i)) = str) And
            (arrayTwo(colArray(2), colArray(i)) = str)) Or
            ((arrayTwo(colArray(i), colArray(0)) = str) And (arrayTwo(colArray(i), colArray(1)) = str) And
             (arrayTwo(colArray(i), colArray(2)) = str)) Then

            MsgBox(str + " Won")

        End If
        Next

End Sub

Public Sub CheckFour(ByVal str As String)

    If ((arrayTwo(colArray(0), colArray(0)) = str) And (arrayTwo(colArray(1), colArray(1)) = str) And
        (arrayTwo(colArray(2), colArray(2)) = str) And (arrayTwo(colArray(3), colArray(3)) = str)) Or
        ((arrayTwo(colArray(3), colArray(0)) = str) And (arrayTwo(colArray(2), colArray(1)) = str) And
        (arrayTwo(colArray(1), colArray(2)) = str) And (arrayTwo(colArray(0), colArray(3)) = str)) Then

        MsgBox(str + " Won")

    End If

    For i = 0 To colArray.Length - 1

        If ((arrayTwo(colArray(0), colArray(i)) = str) And (arrayTwo(colArray(1), colArray(i)) = str) And
            (arrayTwo(colArray(2), colArray(i)) = str) And (arrayTwo(colArray(3), colArray(i)) = str)) Or
            ((arrayTwo(colArray(i), colArray(0)) = str) And (arrayTwo(colArray(i), colArray(1)) = str) And
            (arrayTwo(colArray(i), colArray(2)) = str) And (arrayTwo(colArray(i), colArray(3)) = str)) Then

            MsgBox(str + " Won")

        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

And so on up to dynamically enter value for `colArray(x,x)`

Comment: Please see [ask]

Answer (score 0):

It might help if we knew the entirety of what you were trying to accomplish.

In any case, you may consider something along these lines:

```
Public Sub CheckN(ByVal str As String, ByVal CheckCount As Integer)
    For i = 0 To CheckCount - 1
        Dim TruthList As New List(Of Boolean)
        For j = 0 To colArray.Length - 1
            If arrayTwo(colArray(i), colArray(j)) = str Then
                TruthList.Add(True)
            End If
        Next
        If TruthList.Distinct.Count < 2 Then
            MsgBox(str + " Won")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```